# How to call NSMenu validateMenuItem ?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenuitem

I need dynamically enabling voice on a NSMenu. 
The first check is done with validateMenuItem in this way:

```
-(BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)menuItem{ 
    NSMenuItem *item = [self.menu itemAtIndex:0];

    if(menuItem == item){ 
        return self.streamIsOpen;     
    }
    return YES;
}
```

How can i check again over this function during my application lifecycle ? 
Do I need to attach every time a new menu to relaunch this check ?

Comment: Can't you just call `self.streamIsOpen` yourself whenever you want to know that info?

Comment: ??? I check over this info because it is the key to enable or not the item menu.

Comment: The menu will work that out for itself, with the help of your `validateMenuItem` implementation.  You shouldn't need to do anything else.